Error: missing attribute 'value' LLVM ERROR: Failed to infer result type(s). occuring while trying to convert .h5 file to .tflite file
I had trained a mobilenet model and exported the model into a .h5 file after training. I need to convert it into a .tflite file to use it in a mobile application, but I am not able to convert it as I am getting multiple errors.
import tensorflow as tf

loadmodel = tf.keras.models.load_model('trained_model.h5')
loadmodel.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loadmodel) 
model = converter.convert()

with open('trained_model.tflite' , 'wb') as file: 
    file.write(model)

This is the code. The model was trained and exported to a .h5 file with Tensorflow 2.16.1 and Keras 3.3.3
This is the error message I get when I try to run the above program:

error: missing attribute 'value'
LLVM ERROR: Failed to infer result type(s).


Hi Los , To resolve this issue, there are some points you can try like first one is updating the TensorFlow sometime compatibility cases error, second one is if your model contains custom layers or operations,tensorflow lite might struggle to convert them. you can also first save the model, then convert that  to tflight.

Thank you for the reply. I ended up saving the model first, loading it back up again, and then converting it to tflite.
